# How to set and change the first value of select dropdown in HTML through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a following dropdown:-

```
<select id="myselct">
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
    <option value="2">Three</option>
</select>
```

I wanna change the first value (value=0) from One to a different text.

Something like this that I tried didn't work:-

```
$("select#myselect option[value='One']").val("Change Value");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
$("#myselect option[value='0']").val("Change Value");
```

You are passing the text content as the value. That is the problem.

If you still want to use the text content then use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector,

```
$("#myselect option:contains(One)").val("Change Value");
```

But note that `:contains()` selector is a case sensitive one. Be careful while use it.

If you want to change the text of the option, then use,

```
$("#myselect option[value='0']").text("Change Value");
```

Comment: Lol repo for free. Good catch. +1

Comment: Hi Raja, I guess I was not clear. I wanna change text of first value to a different text. As in text of "One" to a different text. I rephrased the question.

Comment: @Steve Then use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve what you need, considering this has been answered I will just add some additional ways to address the issue, maybe someone will find those useful.

All these will change the text of the first entry in the dropdown list:

```
//First three examples change the first child regardless of value;
$('#mySelect option:first-child').text("Change Value");

$('#mySelect').find('option').first().text("Change Value");

$('#mySelect option').eq(0).text("Change Value");

//Assuming the first element has a value of "0";
$('#mySelect option[value="0"]').text("Change Value");
```

If you'd like to change the value, not the text then you can use .val() instead of .text().

**Note:** *I have changed the ID of your select in my example to 'mySelect', because there was a slight typo.*

Answer (score 1):

This will automatically change from given value to to be change value.

code below to replace `one` with `change value`

```
$('#myselct option').each(function() {
     $(this).text($(this).html().replace(/\bOne\b/g, 'Change Value'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the content of option with calling the .text("Change Value") function on the query result. Like so:

```
$("select#myselect option[value='1']").text("Change Value");
```

Alternatively you could query by option content:

```
$("select#myselect option:contains('One')").text("Change Value");
```

In the html you misspelled the id attribute of select.